# voronoi_plot_2d function giving me error with standard code from Scipy page

Tags: python, plot, scipy, voronoi

To compute a 2D Voronoi Diagrams I've used the code from the scipy page

```
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2],[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]])
vor = Voronoi(points)
voronoi_plot_2d(vor)
plt.show()
```

But then I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "train_word2vec.py", line 84, in <module>
      voronoi_plot_2d(vor)
   File "<decorator-gen-10>", line 2, in voronoi_plot_2d
TypeError: _held_figure() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I've updated my version of "pip" just in case, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: You seem to be running  a very old version  of scipy.  Maybe try `pip install scipy --upgrade`? `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)` should show 1.5.2 for the latest version.

Comment: Oh ! Thank you, it was just that.

Answer (score -1):

You should add the line as:
import numpy as np

Good luck!

Comment: what has numpy got to do with this?